# What does "jellicle" mean?

Tags: meaning, slang

What does "jellicle" mean? It's from the YouTube show Screen Rant ([5:18](https://youtu.be/mUAYXyeVTC8)). I can't find the meaning of this word and consequently can't grasp the concept of the "jellicle motivation". All I managed to find is "Jellicle Cats" but it definitely doesn't come in handy

Comment: This is the ScreenRant video Ryan did about Cats, which has more discussion of "jellicle": https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XsNAu72v2Yc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jellicle is a fictional word made up by the poet T.S. Eliot in a series of poetry about cats that was later adapted into a musical (and also a much-mocked feature film). Jellicle Cats is the reference that ScreenRant is making there--the "Jellicle Ball," which the show Cats is centered on, is a story where the cat who is voted the winner of the Jellicle Ball gets to die and ascend to heaven or possibly some sort of reincarnation. The cat who wins is an elderly cat who has had a terrible life.

Since the character being discussed also wants to die after living for over 400 years, Ryan makes a joke by referring to his motivation as "jellicle."